# getting exception when running soup findall loop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, findall

i'm trying to see if specific string it in a table . so i have tried to find it with soup.find all .
my code is :

```
for i in soup:
    tmp = soup.findAll("td", {"class": "spec-name"})
    tmp2 = soup.findAll("td", {"class": "spec-value"})
    str1 = tmp[i]
    str2 = tmp[i+1]
    if ('Touch' in str1 and 'yes' in str2 or 'Screen' in str1 and 'YES' in str2):
        IsTouch = "touch screen, "
        FIsTouch = 'yes'
    if ('Touch' in str1 and 'NO' in str2 or 'Screen' in str1 and 'No' in str2):
        IsTouch = "not screen touch"
        FIsTouch = 'no'
        break
```

i would like to see if the "yes" is inline with the category "touch"

but - i'm getting except .

what i'm i doing wrong ?

Comment: What is the exception?

Answer (score 0):

i have managed to find a solution with 2 for loops :

```
def get_touch(short_desc,tempCat,soup):  
for i in soup.findAll("td", {"class": "spec-name"}):
    tmp=str(i)
    if ('Touch' in tmp or 'touch' in tmp):
        for z in soup.findAll("td", {"class": "spec-value"}):
            tmp2=str(z)
            if('NO' in tmp2 or 'no' in tmp2 or 'No' in tmp2 or 'no' in tmp2):
                IsTouch = "not touch screen, "
                FIsTouch = 'no'
                break
            elif ('YES' in tmp2 or 'yes' in tmp2 or 'Yes' in tmp2):
                IsTouch = "touch screen, "
                FIsTouch = 'yes'
                break
        else:
            continue
```